# asp.net webforms literally show viewstate on browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms

After end user clicked a menu link from menu, it literally shows viewState to user and viewState only.

Like below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="/qwertyuiop">
```

It's IE 8, Windows XP.

What could cause this?

Answer (score -1):

My solution is this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8

That computer been running for 17 days.